# Missing right parenthesis in Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find, for shop S9, the friend of the user who posted the most number of reviews for it.

I have the following query:

```
select friend_id 
  from friends 
 where user_id = ( select author_id 
                     from posted_reviews_tab   
                    where rownum <= 1 
                      and reviewid in ( select w.reviews.reviewid 
                                          from wall_tab w  
                                         where w.shopid = 'S9' ) 
                    group by author_id 
                    order by count(author_id) desc );
```

I get the following error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: I've added whitespace to your query, it makes it easier to read (for me) and shows you a lot more easily where there might be a problem. Your GROUP BY, ORDER BY with the rownum predicate is almost certainly not returning what you think it is.

Comment: Can you share the table structure? It will help constructing query faster.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in the select:

```
select friend_id 
  from friends 
 where user_id = ( select author_id 
                     from posted_reviews_tab   
                    where rownum <= 1 
                                        --w.reviews.reviewid is wrong
                      and reviewid in ( select w.reviews.reviewid 
                                          from wall_tab w  
                                         where w.shopid = 'S9' ) 
                    group by author_id 
                    order by count(author_id) desc );
```

If that is not a typo, you will have to make a [join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) to arrive at '.reviews' since that syntax is not possible.

Comment: Ok..so I need to use joins..I am fairly new to this !